# where can I ask in other languages?

Tags: discussion

where can I ask my question using other languages? I'm not good with english and would like to ask in portuguese or italian.

Comment: That's a tough one, you can try at the ubuntuforums.org there's sub forums for specific languages.

Comment: I just want to point out how important this question is to Ubuntu's core philosophy. Not only the very idea of openness, but particularly the Ubuntu ideal that computing is for all of us, and not only those of us who speak English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/locallanguage for Non-English support ressources.

For Italian there's a web forum at http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/, for Brasilian Portuguese at http://ubuntuforum-br.org/

Answer (score 3):

On the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) site, you can propose new Stack Exchange sites, including sites in languages other than English.

A few examples of existing proposals:

- [Persian Information Technology and Computer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer)
- [Ubuntu (in German)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30384/ubuntu-in-german) (with [some discussion on extending to Linux or even unix in general](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/abgrenzung-zu-anderen-linux-distributionen))
- [Software Development (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/software-development-in-portuguese)

Note that a site would not have to be specifically about Ubuntu — you can ask Ubuntu questions on a site about [unix in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or even about [all computer hardware and software](https://superuser.com/). My recommendation on the right size of a site is unix in general.

If you decide to create an Area 51 proposal, tell all your Portuguese or Italian-speaking friends! The site will be created if and when it has a critical mass of committed users.

Answer (score 0):

See http://asklinux.ru/ubuntu for Russian languages users

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).